# Slide event with jqSlider and knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a bindingHandler like so:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.percentageSlider = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().percentageSliderOptions || {};
    $(element).slider(options);
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidechange", function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable($(element).slider("value"));
    });
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).slider("destroy");
    });
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slide", function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable($(element).slider("value"));
    });
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = lo.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    $(element).slider("value", value);

}
};
```

And a template binding the slider like so:

```
<tr>
    <td class="caption-cell">@Translate("EditProbability")</td>
    <td width="75%">
        <div style="float:left;" data-bind="percentageSlider: probability, percentageSliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 100, range: 'min', step: 10}"></div>
        <div style="float:left;margin:0 0 0 10px" data-bind="dynamicText: function(){ return probability() + '%'; }"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The handler dynamicText looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dynamicText = {
'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = lo.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    if (typeof value === 'function') {
        value = value(element);
    }
    if ((value === null) || (value === undefined)) {
        value = "";
    }
    if (typeof element.innerText == "string") { element.innerText = value; }
    else { element.textContent = value; }
}
};
```

Now my problem is that the slider has irregular behaviour, sometimes I can't get to 100% and sometimes the value is a couple of tens away from what it should be. If I just click once on the slider it always goes to the right position. I want the percentage to update while sliding the slider and I also want the slider to get updated correctly by knockout (with the update event). What approach should I take here? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you wire it up on JsFiddle or something so that we can take a look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/yumLr/

Your problem is that you need to use: ui.value to get the updated handle values in the slide and slidechange event handlers.  Note the changed event handler signatures.

Answer (score 3):

Johns, solution is excellent, I am simply posting this because I don't believe that it actual addressed the original issue.

I believe that the actual issue is the way the value was being pulled in the update function. The line:

```
var value = lo.unwrap(valueAccessor());
```

is erroneous. If I update that line to:

```
var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
```

both the original solution, without utilizing the event and ui parameters, and the proposed solution seem to function identically.

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/JTY8v/4/